# Network problems on one device

Tags: windows, networking, device, ping

I currently have a problem, that some packages are getting dropped in my local network.
But just on one device.
[Ping to local router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fFpZ.png)

Here you can see a ping to my router. I only have this problem on my pc. Mobilephone and Laptops are completly fine.
I tried a network card and two Wlan usb sticks all with the same problem.

Does somebody a clue on what could cause these problems?

*OS: Windows 10 21H2

*CPU usage ideling around 4-10%

*RAM usage 40%

*Network usage 0-1%

Comment: Make sure to visit the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit broad - there are so many things that can disturb a network connection, from physical issues (i.e. cable defects, WIFI interference), to driver problems, CPU bottlenecks, etc.  That being said, I would tip at a CPU bottleneck (app using most or all of your CPU), but even that is by no means certain.

Take a look at you CPU usage with TaskManager or ProcessExplorer (from the Sysinternals package).  They both also show network usage.  If your machine shows excessive CPU (constantly over 30% with frequent peeks), then you might want to explorer the reasons for that, and there can be many.

Using those same tools you can also try to identify apps that are possibly using alot of network bandwidth.

Windows has much happening in the background and those processes require resources (CPU, RAM, Network, Harddisk, etc.).  Should any of those resources be limited then, you can easily see issues as you describe as there is a certain interdependence between those resources, i.e. you have many apps running with limited RAM, that leads to paging and as the hard disk is slow, the CPU is then busy with data shoveling and can't keep up with the NIC requests.

However, I am theorizing here.  Supply some hard data (machine config, OS Info, Network info/config, task list, CPU usage, etc.) and we can continue.

Comment: *CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600X
*RAM: 16GB
*OS: Windows 10 21H2

*CPU usage ideling around 4-10%
*RAM usage 40%
*Network usage 0-1%